# Access geometry shaders on WSL2 Ubuntu 22.04 LTS?

Tags: opengl, shader, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I would like to use geometry shaders. But it seems they are not available on WSL2. How can I check, or enable them ?

However, I can read this in `glxinfo`:

```
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.1 Mesa 22.0.5
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.10
OpenGL ES profile extensions:
    GL_ANGLE_pack_reverse_row_order, GL_ANGLE_texture_compression_dxt3,
    GL_ANGLE_texture_compression_dxt5, GL_APPLE_texture_max_level,
    GL_EXT_EGL_image_storage, GL_EXT_base_instance,
    GL_EXT_blend_func_extended, GL_EXT_blend_minmax,
    GL_EXT_color_buffer_float, GL_EXT_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_sub_texture,
    GL_EXT_depth_clamp, GL_EXT_discard_framebuffer,
    GL_EXT_disjoint_timer_query, GL_EXT_draw_buffers,
    GL_EXT_draw_buffers_indexed, GL_EXT_draw_elements_base_vertex,
    GL_EXT_draw_instanced, GL_EXT_float_blend, GL_EXT_frag_depth,
    GL_EXT_geometry_point_size, GL_EXT_geometry_shader,  <---------- HERE
```

My configuration is:

```
C:\> wsl --version
WSL version: 1.0.3.0
Kernel version: 5.15.79.1
WSLg version: 1.0.47
MSRDC version: 1.2.3575
Direct3D version: 1.606.4
DXCore version: 10.0.25131.1002-220531-1700.rs-onecore-base2-hyp
Windows version: 10.0.22621.963

C:\> systeminfo

OS Name:                   Microsoft Windows 11 Education
OS Version:                10.0.22621 N/A Build 22621
OS Manufacturer:           Microsoft Corporation
OS Configuration:          Standalone Workstation
OS Build Type:             Multiprocessor Free

$ glxinfo | head -n100
name of display: :0
display: :0  screen: 0
direct rendering: Yes
server glx vendor string: SGI
server glx version string: 1.4
server glx extensions:
    GLX_ARB_context_flush_control, GLX_ARB_create_context,
    GLX_ARB_create_context_no_error, GLX_ARB_create_context_profile,
    GLX_ARB_fbconfig_float, GLX_ARB_framebuffer_sRGB, GLX_ARB_multisample,
    GLX_EXT_create_context_es2_profile, GLX_EXT_create_context_es_profile,
    GLX_EXT_fbconfig_packed_float, GLX_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB,
    GLX_EXT_import_context, GLX_EXT_libglvnd, GLX_EXT_no_config_context,
    GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap, GLX_EXT_visual_info, GLX_EXT_visual_rating,
    GLX_MESA_copy_sub_buffer, GLX_OML_swap_method, GLX_SGIS_multisample,
    GLX_SGIX_fbconfig, GLX_SGIX_pbuffer, GLX_SGIX_visual_select_group,
    GLX_SGI_make_current_read
client glx vendor string: Mesa Project and SGI
client glx version string: 1.4
client glx extensions:
    GLX_ARB_context_flush_control, GLX_ARB_create_context,
    GLX_ARB_create_context_no_error, GLX_ARB_create_context_profile,
    GLX_ARB_create_context_robustness, GLX_ARB_fbconfig_float,
    GLX_ARB_framebuffer_sRGB, GLX_ARB_get_proc_address, GLX_ARB_multisample,
    GLX_ATI_pixel_format_float, GLX_EXT_buffer_age,
    GLX_EXT_create_context_es2_profile, GLX_EXT_create_context_es_profile,
    GLX_EXT_fbconfig_packed_float, GLX_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB,
    GLX_EXT_import_context, GLX_EXT_no_config_context, GLX_EXT_swap_control,
    GLX_EXT_swap_control_tear, GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap,
    GLX_EXT_visual_info, GLX_EXT_visual_rating, GLX_INTEL_swap_event,
    GLX_MESA_copy_sub_buffer, GLX_MESA_multithread_makecurrent,
    GLX_MESA_query_renderer, GLX_MESA_swap_control, GLX_NV_float_buffer,
    GLX_OML_swap_method, GLX_OML_sync_control, GLX_SGIS_multisample,
    GLX_SGIX_fbconfig, GLX_SGIX_pbuffer, GLX_SGIX_visual_select_group,
    GLX_SGI_make_current_read, GLX_SGI_swap_control, GLX_SGI_video_sync
GLX version: 1.4
GLX extensions:
    GLX_ARB_context_flush_control, GLX_ARB_create_context,
    GLX_ARB_create_context_no_error, GLX_ARB_create_context_profile,
    GLX_ARB_fbconfig_float, GLX_ARB_framebuffer_sRGB,
    GLX_ARB_get_proc_address, GLX_ARB_multisample,
    GLX_EXT_create_context_es2_profile, GLX_EXT_create_context_es_profile,
    GLX_EXT_fbconfig_packed_float, GLX_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB,
    GLX_EXT_import_context, GLX_EXT_no_config_context,
    GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap, GLX_EXT_visual_info, GLX_EXT_visual_rating,
    GLX_MESA_copy_sub_buffer, GLX_MESA_query_renderer, GLX_OML_swap_method,
    GLX_SGIS_multisample, GLX_SGIX_fbconfig, GLX_SGIX_pbuffer,
    GLX_SGIX_visual_select_group, GLX_SGI_make_current_read
Extended renderer info (GLX_MESA_query_renderer):
    Vendor: Microsoft Corporation (0xffffffff)
    Device: D3D12 (NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060 6GB) (0xffffffff)
    Version: 22.0.5
    Accelerated: yes
    Video memory: 71522MB
    Unified memory: no
    Preferred profile: core (0x1)
    Max core profile version: 3.3
    Max compat profile version: 3.3
    Max GLES1 profile version: 1.1
    Max GLES[23] profile version: 3.1
OpenGL vendor string: Microsoft Corporation
OpenGL renderer string: D3D12 (NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060 6GB)
OpenGL core profile version string: 3.3 (Core Profile) Mesa 22.0.5
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 3.30
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
    GL_AMD_conservative_depth, GL_AMD_draw_buffers_blend,
    GL_AMD_multi_draw_indirect, GL_AMD_shader_trinary_minmax,
    GL_AMD_texture_texture4, GL_ANGLE_texture_compression_dxt3,
    GL_ANGLE_texture_compression_dxt5, GL_ARB_ES2_compatibility,
    GL_ARB_ES3_1_compatibility, GL_ARB_ES3_compatibility,
    GL_ARB_arrays_of_arrays, GL_ARB_base_instance, GL_ARB_blend_func_extended,
    GL_ARB_clear_buffer_object, GL_ARB_compressed_texture_pixel_storage,
    GL_ARB_compute_shader, GL_ARB_compute_variable_group_size,
    GL_ARB_conditional_render_inverted, GL_ARB_conservative_depth,
    GL_ARB_copy_buffer, GL_ARB_debug_output, GL_ARB_depth_buffer_float,
    GL_ARB_depth_clamp, GL_ARB_direct_state_access, GL_ARB_draw_buffers,
    GL_ARB_draw_buffers_blend, GL_ARB_draw_elements_base_vertex,
    GL_ARB_draw_indirect, GL_ARB_draw_instanced,
    GL_ARB_explicit_attrib_location, GL_ARB_explicit_uniform_location,
    GL_ARB_fragment_coord_conventions, GL_ARB_fragment_shader,
    GL_ARB_framebuffer_no_attachments, GL_ARB_framebuffer_object,
    GL_ARB_framebuffer_sRGB, GL_ARB_get_program_binary,
    GL_ARB_get_texture_sub_image, GL_ARB_gpu_shader5, GL_ARB_half_float_pixel,
    GL_ARB_half_float_vertex, GL_ARB_indirect_parameters,
    GL_ARB_instanced_arrays, GL_ARB_internalformat_query,
    GL_ARB_internalformat_query2, GL_ARB_invalidate_subdata,
    GL_ARB_map_buffer_alignment, GL_ARB_map_buffer_range, GL_ARB_multi_bind,
    GL_ARB_multi_draw_indirect, GL_ARB_occlusion_query2,
    GL_ARB_parallel_shader_compile, GL_ARB_pixel_buffer_object,
    GL_ARB_point_sprite, GL_ARB_program_interface_query,
    GL_ARB_provoking_vertex, GL_ARB_robustness, GL_ARB_sample_shading,
    GL_ARB_sampler_objects, GL_ARB_seamless_cube_map,
    GL_ARB_separate_shader_objects, GL_ARB_shader_atomic_counter_ops,
    GL_ARB_shader_atomic_counters, GL_ARB_shader_bit_encoding,
    GL_ARB_shader_draw_parameters, GL_ARB_shader_image_load_store,
    GL_ARB_shader_image_size, GL_ARB_shader_objects,
    GL_ARB_shader_storage_buffer_object, GL_ARB_shader_subroutine,
    GL_ARB_shader_texture_lod, GL_ARB_shading_language_420pack,
    GL_ARB_shading_language_include, GL_ARB_shading_language_packing,
```

Comment: Are you trying to use desktop GL 3.3 or OpenGL ES 3.1?

Comment: I am just trying to use the geometry shaders. It works on Windows, but not on WSL

Comment: "*I am just trying to use the geometry shaders*" Geometry shaders are a component of a graphics API. My question is which API are you trying to use to use that functionality?

Comment: I am using SFML 2.51

Comment: SFML doesn't directly do graphics; it's just a wrapper around graphics APIs. So which graphics API did you ask *them* to use? Or does SFML even offer you a choice?

Comment: I have absolutely no idea which API uses SFML behind the scenes.

Comment: But you kind of need to know that, since you're trying to *use* that API behind SFML's back. SFML is a 2D API; none of its functionality needs to use geometry shaders, so it doesn't use them. So if you're trying to use geometry shaders through SFML, the only way to do that is to use SFML to create and manage your window and then, outside of SFML's knowledge, talk directly to the graphics API to use GSs.

Comment: Not sure I follow you, from SFML you can load the three kind of shaders : vertex, geometry and fragment. I tried under Windows 11 and I can access my geometry shader using SFML. The issue though is when I try to run the same code from WSL2, using the same SFML library. This time the geometry isn't accessible.